# Wordpress ACF get_field( ) not returning value

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using the `advanced custom field` plugin for `Wordpress`. I am having difficulty displaying a `field` on my page.

Basically I've created a field group and assigned `id's` to the members of that group. I then use the `get_field('field_name')` function to store the value of this field in a variable and `echo` it on the screen. However this is returning `false`.

I've also tried using `the_field('field_name')` but this returns `null`. I then read somewhere If you are trying to access a field outside of the Wordpress loop you must pass the `post id` as a parameter to the `get_field()/the_field()` methods.

I've tried that and still the same result...Does anyone have any idea as to what is the problem?

This is my code:

```
<?php get_header();
      $postID = get_the_ID();
      the_field('the-title', $postID); //Nothing being returned...
      die(); 
?>
```

Comment: Same problem did you ever figured it out? post ID exists, field exist in database i'm echoing get_field and nada.

Answer (score 15):

If you're using `WP_Query()` before using `get_field()`, you need to reset the query using `wp_reset_query()` function. I hope it'll solve this issue.

Comment: This usually will be the answer. Using multiple template partials (which possibly can have many queries which never reset) will cause the a mix up. Even using `global $post` will not help in this instance.

Answer (score 4):

You're using get_the_ID() outside of the loop.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID

You could try:

```
global $post;
the_field( 'the-title', $post->ID );
```

But this would depend on what page you're on.

Which template file is this being used in?

Comment: I suggest avoiding making `global` call - at least do `$GLOBALS['post']->ID`, even better, just use `get_queried_object_id()` :-)

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a loop, then inside that loop you can retrieve the data.

```
<?php while( have_posts() ) : the_post() ?>
     <?php $variable = the_field('the-title'); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue. This was the format of function:

```
function get_field( $selector, $post_id = false, $format_value = true ) {
  // ...
}
```

and I used it like this:

```
get_field( 'event_date', false, false) {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ACF has one more function

```
get_fields([$post_id], [$format_value]);
```

which returns a value of provided ID.
but if we provide only id then by default it considers as post id

but if you provided an ID that is not an id of a post but user, term category, comment, and options tables ID then you have to prefix it like this:

```
// Get values from the current post.
$fields = get_fields();

// Get values from post ID = 1.
$post_fields = get_fields( 1 );

// Get values from user ID = 2.
$user_fields = get_fields( 'user_2' );

// Get values from category ID = 3.
$term_fields = get_fields( 'term_3' );

// taxonomy name.
$term_fields = get_fields( 'category_3' );

// Get values from comment ID = 4.
$comment_fields = get_fields( 'comment_4' );

// Get values from ACF Options page.
$option_fields = get_fields( 'options' );

// using 'option'.
$option_fields = get_fields( 'option' );
```

as described in the official [docs](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_fields/)

I found this when I have to work on a project where I need the value of category term id. this is worked for me outside of the loop.