# ACF get_field() is not returning a value in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type

I am using ACF and CPT cooperatively. I created a shortcode to be placed in a text module in my theme. It works well. Yet, when I call ACF `get_field()`, it's not returning any value. I tried looking into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24887158/wordpress-acf-get-field-not-returning-value) and also this [one](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/get_field-not-returning-values/), but neither works.

I double-checked ACF fields name. Also tried to change the input type from text to number but still no hope.

**Development Environment**

- WordPress Version: 5.2.2 (Latest at the moment)
- Theme/Child Theme Version: Divi 3.25.3

The shortcode I created:

```php
  <?php
    add_shortcode('RESTAURANT_MENU', 'fetch_menu_products');
    function fetch_menu_products($atts)
    {
      $atts = shortcode_atts(array(
        'category_name' => ''
      ), $atts);
      $category_name = $atts['category_name'];

      $args = array(
        'category_name' => $category_name,
        'post_type' => 'menu',
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_status' => 'publish'
      );

      $output = '';
      $menu_products = get_posts($args);
      foreach ($menu_products as $menu_product) {
        setup_postdata($menu_product);
        $output .= '<section class="menu-item-wrapper">';
        $output .= '<h3 class="menu-item__title">' . $menu_product->post_title . '</h3>';
        $output .= '<div class="menu-item">';
        $output .= '<div class="menu-item-description">';
        $output .= '<p class="menu-item-description__text">' . $menu_product->post_content . '</p>';
        $output .= '</div>';
        $output .= '<ul class="menu-prices-list">';
        if (get_field("regular_size_price") || get_field("large_size_price")) {
          $output .= '<li class="menu-prices-list--item">R ' . get_field("regular_size_price", $menu_product->ID)  . ' Currency</li>';
          $output .= '<li class="menu-prices-list--item">L ' . get_field("large_size_price", $menu_product->ID) . ' Currency</li>';
        }
        if (get_field("price")) {
          $output .= '<li class="menu-prices-list--item">' . get_field("price", $menu_product->ID)  . ' Currency</li>';
        }
        $output .= '</ul>';
        $output .= '</div>';
        $output .= '</section>';
      }
      wp_reset_postdata();
      return $output;
    }
```

Can any help me find out why isn't it returning any value, please? Thank you.

> Update: The ACF Location Rules

[image: ACF Location Rules]

Comment: Can you try get_post_meta($menu_product->ID, 'regular_size_price');  and see what is returning? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/

Comment: @NewUser it returns nothing.

Comment: @NewUser I managed to use your method `get_post_meta($menu_product->ID, 'regular_size_price')[0]` and neglect using `get_field()` function provided by ACF.

Comment: Yes I have came through this situation many times. For some reasons get_field doesn't work sometimes. So rather than using get_field() most of the times I use get_post_meta()

Comment: @NewUser Thanks a lot, sir. Can you please add your answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I have added my answer. Please check it.

Comment: @Tes3awy The function that @NewUser asked you try should have had an extra parameter in it (so it won't be returned as an array, then you can easily just echo it). You should change this to `echo get_post_meta($menu_product->ID, 'regular_size_price', true);` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `get_post_meta()` instead of `get_field()`. As you are already using `ACF` then use this code to get value from post meta

`get_post_meta($menu_product->ID, 'regular_size_price')[0]`

For more help on `get_post_meta()` you can check this [link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/)

Comment: This only works for flat values. `get_post_meta` doesn't return array structures

Answer (score 0):

If my assumption is correct, your `li` elements are not being printed when you return the `$output` variable. That should be the case since you are using `get_field` function outside of **theloop** without passing post id in if statement.

Below is the corrected code:

```
if (get_field("regular_size_price", $menu_product->ID) || get_field("large_size_price", $menu_product->ID)) {
    $output .= '<li class="menu-prices-list--item">R ' . get_field("regular_size_price", $menu_product->ID)  . ' Currency</li>';
    $output .= '<li class="menu-prices-list--item">L ' . get_field("large_size_price", $menu_product->ID) . ' Currency</li>';
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: The problem is not in the `if` condition. If I remove the the `if`, I get `R empty Currency`.

Comment: @Tes3awy I see that you managed to get the data using `get_post_meta` and I am quite surprised that this didn't work with `get_field`. Just for the purpose of better understanding the underlying issue can you do `var_dump(get_field("regular_size_price", $menu_product->ID))` and post the results. I am under the impression that the data is not being saved in proper format somehow.

Comment: Using `var_dump` prints `NULL` which is very weird because all the fields are populated!

Comment: If you enable debug log in config, you might find more about the issue. There is a possibility that your installation environment is not supported as was the case with [this one](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/cpt-loop-not-returning-get_field-but-does-get_post_meta/)

Comment: I tried to do a clean install, and install only ACF, It doesn't work. I am suspecting that it has something to do with Divi itself. Yet, the `get_post_meta` works well with the current installation. So I'll go with it for now.

Comment: Well getting things to work should be the first priority so wise choice there. Trying to identify the problem helps you handle similar issue in future so in free time trying to fix this and sharing the solution will be a help to the community.

Comment: One more thing, `setup_postdata` requires the passed variable name to be `$post`. So it should be `global $post; $post = $menu_product; setup_postdata($post);`. That way you can directly use `the_title` and other core functions.

Comment: Thanks a lot, sir. And sure once I figure out the right solution; not the easy one; I'll share it (Y).

Comment: Good luck mate!!